Json formatted messages using Log4j
I'm trying to get log4j to log messages with specific fields in json format. There is a spec the logging has to follow.
log_fmt.json
{
  "name": {
    "$resolver": "map",
    "field": "name"
  },
  "name2": {
    "$resolver": "map",
    "field": "test"
  }
}

log4j2.xml snippet
<JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:log_fmt.json"/>
<Appenders>
  <Console name="CONSOLE">
  </Console>
</Appenders>

Java
MapMessage mm = new MapMessage();
mm.put("name", "nameValue");
mm.put("test", "testValue");
log.atInfo().log(mm);

Expected Output
{
  "name": "nameValue",
  "name2": "testValue"
}

I've tried JSONLayout but that is deprecated and doesn't seem to do what I want. I can't figure out how to tell the Appender to use the template. Layout I think is a valid element under Appender but I don't see any way to connect the two.

Something like this

The JsonTemplateLayout element must be a child of the Console element. You can use the log4j-config-2.xsd schema to validate your configuration file.

Try to store your custom JSON layout on the classpath and reference it from the log4j config:
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:MyCustomLayout.json"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

